# Matlab, choice of algorithm in optimization is ignored

Tags: mathematical-optimization, matlab, quadprog

When does Matlab's quadprog, ignore my choice of algorithm? 
I select interior-point-convex, but it uses active-set algorithm for me. What does it indicate?

BTW, my objective is quadratic and convex, unless there is some unknown bug in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find anything similar for `quadprog`, but in [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/optim/ug/lsqnonlin.html) for `lsqnonlin` it says:

> The Algorithm option specifies a preference for which algorithm to
>   use. It is only a preference, because certain conditions must be met
>   to use each algorithm. For the trust-region-reflective algorithm, the
>   nonlinear system of equations cannot be underdetermined; that is, the
>   number of equations (the number of elements of F returned by fun) must
>   be at least as many as the length of x. The Levenberg-Marquardt
>   algorithm does not handle bound constraints.

I suspect something similar is the case with `quadprog`.

Comment: Thank you Rody. Yes, I think the same way. But do not know what are those conditions for quadprog.

Answer (score 0):

Tell us HOW you called the code, as almost always when this happens, the user simply did not call the code properly. Did you pass in the options structure? Simply calling optimset does nothing. You must pass the options into the code.

Comment: Yes, passing options are done correctly. I can easily check by putting a break in quadprog that they are received correctly. Algorithm: 'interior-point-convex' is received.